# Dynamically Changing Two Checkboxes ForeColor During Runtime

Tags: vb.net

So i have this program in visual studio 2008 that will let the user select a month and a year and then dynamically changes all the checkboxes fore color which texts corresponds to the date of the selected month's Saturdays and Sundays.

lets say "Let i = 1" on the first run that is the date of first sunday and the very first day of January 2017 ((UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada))

I know using for each will let the program loop to each control in Me.Controls so I don't think it would not read the first IF statement

```
    If cb.Text = i-1
```

and that only the ELIF would exit the FOR LOOP.

but if I change the first statement into

```
    if cb.Text = i+1
```

it worked. Anyone please tell me whats wrong with it.. I just don't get any errors or warnings just this logical error I think?

```
    Dim cb
        While i < 31
            For Each cb In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf cb Is CheckBox Then
                    If cb.Text = i - 1 Then
                        cb.ForeColor = Color.Blue
                    ElseIf cb.Text = i Then
                        cb.ForeColor = Color.Red
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            i += 7
        End While
```

Answer (score 0):

so this is how I solved my own problem, let the user select a month and a year, calculate the days and the first sunday then go on....

it is because the FOR EACH LOOP starts with the last control you added on the group of controls or in your form so I used the normal FOR LOOP and direct cast the object so it will look on the names of the control, names must be arranged in a manner of array. like c1,c2,c3....

```
    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim nMonths As Integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(ComboBox2.Text, ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1)
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim customDate As Date = FormatDateTime(CDate(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1 & "/1/" & ComboBox2.Text), DateFormat.ShortDate)

    While customDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday
        customDate = customDate.AddDays(1)
        i += 1
    End While
    x = i - 1

    Dim cb
    'set visible
    For n = 1 To nMonths
        cb = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + n.ToString()), CheckBox)
        cb.Visible = True
    Next

    If nMonths = 31 Then
        'set sundays and saturdays checkboxes fore color
        While i <= 31
            Dim cb1 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + x.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            Dim cb2 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + i.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            i += 7
            x += 7
        End While
    ElseIf nMonths = 30 Then
        'set sundays and saturdays checkboxes fore color
        While i <= 30
            Dim cb1 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + x.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            Dim cb2 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + i.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            i += 7
            x += 7
        End While
    ElseIf nMonths = 29 Then
        'set sundays and saturdays checkboxes fore color
        While i <= 29
            Dim cb1 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + x.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb1.ForeColor = Color.Blue 'satudays
            Dim cb2 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + i.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb2.ForeColor = Color.Red 'sundays
            i += 7
            x += 7
        End While
    ElseIf nMonths = 28 Then
        'set sundays and saturdays checkboxes fore color
        While i <= 28
            Dim cb1 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + x.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            Dim cb2 = DirectCast(Me.Controls("chk" + i.ToString()), CheckBox)
            cb2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            i += 7
            x += 7
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```